# How can I spin up test chef-server to test chef-automate using chef

Tags: chef-infra, databags, chef-vault

I have a scenario where I want to setup chef-automate using chef. In order to test chef-automate I need chef-server. I was able to do it on local machine, installing chef-server and chef-automate. In order to do that I need `automate.license` which I can get for local testing from chef website. Though it has one-month validity.

In order to do that using chef, I need to have a license in my test-kitchen so everytime I run test kitchen in can install chef-server and chef-automate server.

I have chef enterprise license. I thought if I can use data bags or chef-vault but nothing seems to work as it will expose enterprise license.

How can I achieve this without having renewing license every month for testing?

Comment: This was cross-posted to Slack, and redirected to the Chef Software sales team on there.

Answer (score 0):

After talking to slack support team on slack, I was suggested following ideas. I thought it might help someone so posting it here.

1. Use `enterprise key`. It is not that special. If someone gets that key they are able to use chef-automate and in that, case key can be regenerated.
2. Try to get 1-node key from Account Manager which can be used specifically for testing.